# Custom template tag to get a remaining days in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model like this:

```
class WeddingDate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField(help_text="Date should be in 1991-07-22 format!")
```

User enters the date of their wedding. And, I find the remaining days for their wedding and show in `base.html`. I am trying to create a custom template tag for it.

I have create a directory called templatetags and created a file called `remainingdays.py`

```
from models import WeddingDate
from django import template
from datetime import date

register = template.Library()

def get_remaining_day(user):
    date = WeddingDate.objects.get(pk=user)
    current_date = date.today()
    days = date.date - current_date
    return days.days
```

Now, how do I displays it in template like `{% get_remaining_day %}`

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to choose what type of template tag you are writing. It is probably easiest to use an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags). You also need to [register the template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag) so that it's available in your template:

Either below your function:

```
def get_remaining_day(user):
    ...
register.assignment_tag('get_remaining_day', get_remaining_day)
```

or as a decorator:

```
@register.assignment_tag(name='get_remaining_day')
def get_remaining_day(user):
    ...
```

Now you can call it from your template as:

```
{% get_remaining_day as day %}
{{ day }}
```

Comment: I can't find `Assignment Tag` in Django 1.5

Comment: They're there: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags. Alternatively you can use a "simple tag" and just print the day directly. Eitherway, you still need to register you tag to have it available in your template

Comment: `Invalid block tag: 'get_remaining_day', expected 'endblock'` I have used `Assignment Tag`

Comment: @user2032220 you should read the whole documentation page. You need to load your tag library in your template.